# Printing dynamic html templates onto page with JavaScript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html template:

```
<template id="photo-template">
    <div class="template-border">
        <p class="name"></p>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want to display multiple of these on the same page but change the name depending on some strings in a javascript array. This is the code I have to display the templates:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var tmpl = document.getElementById('photo-template').content.cloneNode(true);
    $("#content").append(tmpl);
    $(".name").text(javascript_array[i]);
}
```

The result should be 3 templates on the page each with a different name, but, for some reason, it prints the 3 templates only with the last name in the array. For example if I had an array {"Alex","John","Thomas"} all 3 templates would have Thomas as the name. If I did

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {...}
```

all 3 templates would have the name John. So, how do I make then appear with the different names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `$(".name").text()` you target all the elements that have the `.name` class, so all your templates. You need to be more specific with your selector to select only the template you just added.

You could do :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var tmpl = document.getElementById('photo-template').content.cloneNode(true);
    $("#content").append(tmpl);
    $(".name").eq(i).text(javascript_array[i]);
}
```

Just by adding `.eq(i)` you'll select the current template you're working with.
(https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Wow, so simple. I've been trying to solve this for hours. Thank you!